# Finish proof of Levy's inequality

Tags: probability-theory

**Statement:** For real, symmetric and independent random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ we have $$ P\big(\max_k \vert X_k \vert > \delta\big) \leq 2P\big(\vert S_n \vert >\delta\big)$$
for every $\delta>0$ and where $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

**Sketch of proof:** Define the events
$$A_k = \{ \vert X_1 \vert \leq \delta, \dots, \vert X_{k-1} \vert \leq \delta, \vert X_k \vert > \delta  \}$$
that are disjoint. Then using the assumptions about independence and symmetric we can obtain the following bound:
$$ P(A_k) \leq 2 P(A_k, \vert S_n \vert > \delta).$$
Using that
$$ \{ \max_k \vert X_k \vert > \delta \} \subseteq \bigcup_k A_k $$
and the above bound, we get that

$$ P\big(\max_k \vert X_k \vert > \delta\big) = P\bigg(\bigcup_k A_k \bigg) \leq 2 \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_k, \vert S_n \vert > \delta) = 2 P\bigg(\bigcup_k A_k, \vert S_n \vert > \delta\bigg) \overset{(!)}{=} 2P(\vert S_n \vert > \delta) $$
as desired if the final step can be justified.

**Step (!):** I am not sure how to show this step is true. It would be true if
$$ \{ \vert S_n \vert > \delta \} \subseteq \bigcup_k A_k $$
However if I try taking an $\omega \in \{ \vert S_n \vert > \delta \} $ then I end up stuck at the fact that $\vert \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega) \vert > \delta$. How can I from here get that there exists a $ k \in \{1,\dots,n \} $ s.t. $\omega \in A_k$?

Comment: What mean $\mathbb P(A,B)$ ? Is it $\mathbb P(A\cap B)$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly, to keep notation light

Comment: So obviously $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\subset B$. Therefore $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb P(A)$ and $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb P(B)$.

Comment: This is true but I believe it is possible to show there is equality not just inequality

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay attention to that. At then end, since you want an inequality, at the end, the equality is not relevant...

Comment: Even so using fewer inequalities would make it seem like a tighter bound, wouldn't it? But yes at the end of the day it doesn't matter. But I am still curious :)

Comment: What you have is $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\subset \{|S_n|>\delta \}$, which is enough.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry : you have $\bigcup_{k}A_k\subset \{|S_n|>\delta \}$ which is **not** enough to have the equality.

Comment: Usually, Levy's Inequality: $ \mathsf{P}(\max\limits_{1\le k\le n}|S_k|\ge \delta)\le 2\mathsf{P}(|S_n|\ge \delta) $.